# What is the recommended method to have an image lie side by side with a list?

Tags: graphics, lists, code-review

What I am doing below should suffice but I invite any other better ways. Is there any other better ones?

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{enumitem,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Consider the following image.\\
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item What is your name?
    \item What time is it?
    \item Who am I?
    \item Do you love me?
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not really.  You can replace the first minipage with `\raisebox{-0.5\height}{...}` assuming you still want to align the centers.  You can use minpages to align the bottoms, but not the tops.  For that you need `\rasiebox{\dimexpr \topskip-\height}{...}`

Comment: I do not decide the accepted answer until I am finished checking each answer and find its drawback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can align at top both minipages:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{enumitem,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Consider the following image.

    \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}\vspace{0pt}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}\vspace{0pt}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item What is your name?
    \item What time is it?
    \item Who am I?
    \item Do you love me?
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

And you can omit the first minipage using adjustbox:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{enumitem,graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Consider the following image.\par
    \includegraphics[valign=t,width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item What is your name?
    \item What time is it?
    \item Who am I?
    \item Do you love me?
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Or without any minipage, using `multicol` (but not with `standalone`):

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Consider the following image.
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item What is your name?
    \item What time is it?
    \item Who am I?
    \item Do you love me?
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Or with `\parbox` instead of a minipage (simpler syntax):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Consider the following image.\par
    \includegraphics[valign=t,width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \parbox[t]{.5\linewidth}{
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item What is your name?
    \item What time is it?
    \item Who am I?
    \item Do you love me?
    \end{enumerate}} 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

And for a center or bottom alignment, a simple `tabular` could do the job using `m` or `b` columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,array}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Consider the following image.\par
    \begin{tabular}{m{.5\linewidth}m{.5\linewidth}}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} &
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item What is your name?
    \item What time is it?
    \item Who am I?
    \item Do you love me?
    \end{enumerate}\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Ahem! And also for top alignment with classic `p` columns (that do not need the `array` package but a  *déjà vu*  dirty trick):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,array}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Consider the following image.\par
    \begin{tabular}{p{.5\linewidth}p{.5\linewidth}}\vspace{0pt}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} &
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item What is your name?
    \item What time is it?
    \item Who am I?
    \item Do you love me?
    \end{enumerate}\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

And dubiously for other purposes, but this is a good method for procastination: `:)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,tabto}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Consider the following image.\par
    \vbox to -0pt{
    \includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
    \tab
    \vbox to 2\baselineskip{
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item What is your name?
    \item What time is it?
    \item Who am I?
    \item Do you love me?
    \end{enumerate}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah yes, add an invisible line above the image.  I would have gone with `\hrule height0pt`, but evidently `\vspace{0pt}` works too.

Answer (score 2):

Just some examples with `tcbsidebyside` boxes (from `tcolorbox` package):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Consider the following image.\par
    \tcbsidebyside[blanker, sidebyside gap=5mm]{
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}{%
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item What is your name?
    \item What time is it?
    \item Who am I?
    \item Do you love me?
    \end{enumerate}}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Consider the following image.\par
    \tcbsidebyside[righthand ratio=.4, sidebyside align=top seam, blanker, sidebyside gap=5mm]{%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}{%
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item What is your name?
    \item What time is it?
    \item Who am I?
    \item Do you love me?
    \end{enumerate}}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Consider the following image.\par
    \tcbsidebyside[righthand ratio=.6, sidebyside align=bottom seam, blanker, sidebyside gap=5mm]{%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}{%
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item What is your name?
    \item What time is it?
    \item Who am I?
    \item Do you love me?
    \end{enumerate}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]